# How to push a child into Firebase RealTime Database with a specified key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app using React Native and Firebase RealTime database.

I want to do the following. I want to create a data tree like following.

```
myRoot
  |
  |---myKey: "myValue"
```

But here, I DON'T want to do it as follows.

```
foo = async () => {
   let myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');

   await myRef.set({
      myKey: "myValue"
   })
}
```

Instead, I want to do something like this.

```
writeData = async (key, value) => {
   let myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');

   await myRef.set({
      key: value
   })
}
```

And, then call the function to add data.

```
this.writeData(myKey, myValue);
```

For example, after I called the function as below,

```
this.writeData("myFirstKey", "myFirstValue");
this.writeData("mySecondKey", "mySecondValue");
this.writeData("myThirdKey", "myThirdValue");
```

I need the output as below.

```
myRoot
  |
  |---myFirstKey: "myFirstValue"
  |---mySecondKey: "mySecondValue"
  |---myThirdKey: "myThirdValue"
```

How to do this?

Comment: No question should start with How to push a child :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. I got the point..

```
writeData = async (key, value) => {
   let myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');
   await myRef.child(key).set(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling set on a given object will replace it completely instead of set you can use  update function  like this

```
writeData = async (key, value) => {
 let myRef = firebase.database().ref('myRoot');
   await myRef.update({
     key:value
    })

    }
```